# How to find corner or direction of graph using networkx python?

Tags: python, networkx

I am working on Rectangular Dual Algorithm, where I need to find the corner of graph.
For example, their is X graph, I need to detect the 4 direction or 4 corner NW(North-West), NE(North-East), SW(South-West), and SE(South-East) node of graph.

Imagine you have a graph as added in the picture, and the mentioned NW, NE, SW, and SE are the detected node which we need to find. What is the logic for this can be?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQlUd.png)

Comment: Okay, so from paper, https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/papers/findjr.pdf on page number 19, I1: says much on it. They didnt mentioned how to find corner for the same. Can anybody help me?